# Passing API Request Function To Another Function GoLang

Tags: json, go

**Background -**

I am moving this function to `main()` so the response data is accessible to the rest of my code.

**Example -**

```
func RequestTopMovies(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
  res, err := http.Get(url)
      if err != nil {
        panic(err)
      }
      defer res.Body.Close()

      body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(res.Body)
      if err != nil {
        panic(err)
      }
      var p Payload

      err = json.Unmarshal(body, &p)
      if err != nil {
        panic(err)
      }
      for i := 0; i < len(p.Results); i++ {
       fmt.Println(p.Results[i].Overview) 
    }
}
```

**Question -**

How do I set the response data to be accessible to other places in my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RequestTopMovies is a `http.Handler` type which will get called automatically as a handler function aka controller.

To access the data received, either use something like context (check gorilla/context) or just create a slice or map to hold the data struct so you can access it from somewhere else in the code, i.e.

```
var Temp = map[string]Payload{}
```

And once you unmarshaled the data, store it like

```
Temp[key] = p
```

Then from else where like another handler you can grab the data like

```
func SomeHandler(rw http.ResponseWriter, *http.Request) {
        p := Temp[key]
        // ...
}
```